# Выполнение нескольких цикличных функций

Tags: python, simple-draw

Всем привет. Ломаю голову какой уже день, не могу решить. Есть несколько цикличных функций (в одной падают снежинки бесконечно, в другом крутится солнце и т.д.) и все эти функции разнесены по разным модулям. Я все эти модули импортирую в один и запускаю. Начинает выполняться только самая верхняя функция и пока я ее не завершу, остальные так и не сработают. Как мне при запуске сделать, чтобы одновременно и падали снежинки и крутилось солнце. (Рисовал в библиотеке simple_draw).
Функция радуги:

```
def rainbow(radius=1200, lenght=20, dxy=13):

rainbow_colors = [sd.COLOR_RED, sd.COLOR_ORANGE, sd.COLOR_YELLOW, sd.COLOR_GREEN,
                  sd.COLOR_CYAN, sd.COLOR_BLUE, sd.COLOR_PURPLE]
while True:
    rainbow_colors = [rainbow_colors[-1]] + rainbow_colors[:-1]
    x = 100
    y = -500
    for color in rainbow_colors:
        point = sd.get_point(x, y)
        sd.circle(point, radius, color, lenght)
        x += dxy
        y += dxy
    sd.sleep(0.05)
    if sd.user_want_exit():
        break
```

Функция снега:

```
def snow(n=5):
l = []
for _ in range(n):
    x = sd.random_number(0, 180)
    y = sd.random_number(400, 600)
    z = sd.random_number(10, 30)
    l.append((x, y, z))
while True:
    i = 0
    dx = sd.random_number(-5, 5)
    dy = 5
    for x, y, z in l:
        l.remove((x, y, z))
        x += dx
        y -= dy
        sd.start_drawing()
        point0 = sd.get_point(x - dx, y + dy)
        sd.snowflake(center=point0, length=z, color=sd.background_color)
        point = sd.get_point(x, y)
        sd.snowflake(center=point, length=z, color=sd.COLOR_WHITE)
        sd.finish_drawing()
        sd.sleep(0.0001)
        if y < 40:
            point = sd.get_point(x, y - sd.random_number(-50, 50))
            sd.snowflake(center=point, length=z, color=sd.COLOR_WHITE)
            y += 580
        l.insert(i, (x, y, z))
        i += 1
    if sd.user_want_exit():
        break
```

Эти две функции импортируются в другой модуль и вызываются:

```
r.rainbow(1300, 20, 13)
sn.snow(5)
```

Comment: Не уверен что simple_draw умеет в многопоточность. Покажите свой код

Comment: @CrazyElf добавил код и как его вызываю. Если так делать, то будет сначала радуга переливаться, но как я нажму выход, появится снег и все закроется. Если одна мысль только, запихнуть код снега и радуги в один модуль и под одним while и его уже импортировать.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, поиграться с `yield`, превратив функции в "типа" генераторы.

```
import simple_draw as sd

def rainbow(radius=1200, lenght=20, dxy=13):
    rainbow_colors = [sd.COLOR_RED, sd.COLOR_ORANGE, sd.COLOR_YELLOW, sd.COLOR_GREEN,
                      sd.COLOR_CYAN, sd.COLOR_BLUE, sd.COLOR_PURPLE]
    while True:
        rainbow_colors = [rainbow_colors[-1]] + rainbow_colors[:-1]
        x = 100
        y = -500
        for color in rainbow_colors:
            point = sd.get_point(x, y)
            sd.circle(point, radius, color, lenght)
            x += dxy
            y += dxy
        sd.sleep(0.05)
        yield

def snow(n=5):
    l = []
    for _ in range(n):
        x = sd.random_number(0, 180)
        y = sd.random_number(400, 600)
        z = sd.random_number(10, 30)
        l.append((x, y, z))
    while True:
        i = 0
        dx = sd.random_number(-5, 5)
        dy = 5
        for x, y, z in l:
            l.remove((x, y, z))
            x += dx
            y -= dy
            sd.start_drawing()
            point0 = sd.get_point(x - dx, y + dy)
            sd.snowflake(center=point0, length=z, color=sd.background_color)
            point = sd.get_point(x, y)
            sd.snowflake(center=point, length=z, color=sd.COLOR_WHITE)
            sd.finish_drawing()
            sd.sleep(0.0001)
            if y < 40:
                point = sd.get_point(x, y - sd.random_number(-50, 50))
                sd.snowflake(center=point, length=z, color=sd.COLOR_WHITE)
                y += 580
            l.insert(i, (x, y, z))
            i += 1
        yield

rainbow_gen = rainbow(1000, 20, 13)
snow_gen = snow(5)
while True:
    next(rainbow_gen)
    next(snow_gen)
    if sd.user_want_exit():
        break
```

Только имейте в виду, что всякие `sleep` в каждой из функций будут влиять на время общего цикла, т.к. тела циклов `while` каждой функции в каждой итерации просто выполняются попеременно.

Comment: так все получилось. Спасибо большое! Пойду теперь разбираться подробнее что это за yield

Comment: @airkraft, [Как принято говорить "спасибо" на SO (StackOverflow)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) и  [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;)